# PLSQL Oracle SFTP Connection

Tags: plsql, oracle12c

Is there any way to transfer data through SFTP using oracle PlSql.

I found many exmaples with FTP connnection but no SFTP.

Thank you

Comment: Oracle can run a Java stored procedure (or Python or Javascript if you install the multilingual engine).  There are various Java libraries out there for doing SFTP that you can choose from.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve SFTP operations from PL/SQL with the commercial [OraSFTP package](https://www.didisoft.com/ora-sftp/tutorial/#upload). Sample upload operation is like this:

```
DECLARE 
 connection_id NUMBER; 
 data BLOB;
BEGIN     
 connection_id := ORA_SFTP.CONNECT_HOST('localhost', 22, 'user', 'password');
 
 SELECT blobfield INTO data 
 FROM accounts_payable
 WHERE  account_id = 100;

 ORA_SFTP.UPLOAD(connection_id, data, 'datafile.dat');
 
 ORA_SFTP.DISCONNECT_HOST(connection_id);
END;
/
```

Disclaimer: I work for DidiSoft